# Lock Azure blob during write

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have to update a large file stored as Azure blob. This update will take a few seconds and I need to ensure that no other client ever gets the partially updated file.

As described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-concurrency it should be easy to lock the file for writing but as far as I understand, other clients will still be able to read the file. I could use read locks but that would mean that only one client can read the file and that's not what I want.

According to [Preventing azure blob from being accessed by other service while it's being created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099642/preventing-azure-blob-from-being-accessed-by-other-service-while-its-being-crea?rq=1) it seems that at least new files will be "committed" at the end of an upload but I could not find information what happens when I update an existing file.

So, the question is: What will other clients read during an update (replace) operation?

- Will they read the old file until the new data is committed or
- will they read the partially updated file content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a test for the scenario(I didn't find any official doc about this), updating a 400M file in blob with a 600M file. and during the update(about 10 seconds after starting update), use code to read the blob which is updating.

The test result is that, only the old file can be read during updating.

Comment: Thanks for testing.

Comment: This is a very useful test result.  The fact that the official docs only talk about multiple writers as a problem to be dealt with (via last-write-wins vs optimistic + pessimistic concurrency) is a strong indicator that the concurrent read/write situation is dealt with... but it's good to have this put to the test.  Thanks.